# Resize div on click to fit window (working)and resize back on second click (not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I have a code that allows me to resize W&H of a container to match the window W&H on click, and it's working great, also I want it to resize back on second click but that's not working for me so far...

Here's what i got and a half working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/a05vhgLn/):

```
$('.more').click(function(){
    var isFullscreen = false;
    var d = {};
    var speed = 900; 
    if(!isFullscreen){ // MAXIMIZATION
        d.width = $(window).width();;
        d.height = $(window).height();; 
        isFullscreen = true;
    }
    else{ // MINIMIZATION            
        d.width = "50px";
        d.height =  "50px";            
        isFullscreen = false;
    }

    $(this).animate(d,speed)
    })
```

Comment: u can make use of toggle() for this

Comment: @raghu to be honest i thought of that only after placing the question, will try right away and see if it works and I'll come back with an update

Comment: @raghu I couldn't pull it off, for some reason .toggle will allow me to resize to window W&H, only to a predefined height in px.

Comment: @raghu The thing that's interesting is that if i set a padding for that div it does toggle it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ummmm...your click function always starts by initializing isFullscreen to false (never takes the 'else' branch).  You could make isFullscreen a global variable; move its declaration and intialization outside the function.  If it is supposed to be a 'static' type of variable, you need to initialize it rather differently (starting with giving that click function a name), perhaps:

```
 $('.more').click(function f(){
   f.isFullscreen = (f.isFullscreen===false)?true:false;
```

The very first time the function is called, f.isFullscreen is undefined (not identical to false) so gets set to false. On subsequent calls its value flips, so you don't need the individual lines that set its value in your MAXIMIZATION and MINIMIZATION code blocks.

Comment: Great answer and it works like a charm, thanks, I actually couldn't find out the reason at first so I ended up on creating another click function for an overlay div to resize back. Phew, have a nice day.